# How to execute 2 database operations in only time using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

I want updating 2 database tables in a only execution, if I using `SQL`, I can simple create a `query`

```
$sql = "UPDATE produto SET descricao = 'desc', estoque = '2', preco = '2.00';
UPDATE table2 SET col1 = 'val1', col2 = 'val2', col3 = 'val3';
// and more operations in only database access
";
```

but in `codeigniter` I can only execute this code:

```
    $data = array(
        'descricao'=>$dados[ 'descricao' ],
        'preco_custo'=>$dados['preco_custo'],
        'estoque'=>$dados['estoque']
    );

    $this->db->where( 'id', $dados[ 'id' ] );
    $this->db->update('produto', $data );
```

If I need execute any other operations, I need access database one more time? or has any solutions for execute more operations in only time using `Codeigniter` methods??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use transactions if you want multiple updates

```
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html
```